# Cloudwatch logs from one lambda invocation

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Is there a way to know exactly that a logs belongs to a particular requestId in cloudwatch logs for lambda.

Answer (score 0):

yes the log data has **request Id** in it -

```
....
@requestId 9dbe69e3-21d4-4158-86a4-512be3300208
@timestamp 1577448608126
....
```

Let me know, if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: I am searching for logs in cloudwatch insights. I searched for all the logs where @duration was greater than 20s. Now with the requestId that I got, I again searched. But this time only 3 logs were present. START, END and REPORT. All other intermittent logs are not shown. What am I missing?

Comment: And it looks like REPORT type logs contain @requestId only. All other logs from lambda, do not contain this field.

Comment: is it in cloudwatch insight?

Comment: with this query "fields @ message, @ requestId" , I am seeing @ requestId only in case of START, END and REPORT logs. Other logs contain @ ingestionTime, @ log, @ logstream and @ message

Comment: What runtime/language is this Lambda function? if you look at regular log messages (not START, END or REPORT), does @message actually contain the request id and it's just not getting indexed by CloudWatch Logs?